# My Next Js app isn't building and returing a type error, how do I fix?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth, next.js13

My NextJS 13 app isn't building and is returning a type error but it is completely working on development environment

the type error is shown in this file

```
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
        }),
    ],
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

*the file path is app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts*

**This is the error message shown in the console ⬇️**

```
.next/types/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts:8:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("D:/4 - Coding/Training/NextAuth/next-auth-new/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"), "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | "dynamic" | "dynamicParams" | ... 9 more ... | "PATCH", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'authOptions' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'AuthOptions' is not assignable to type 'never'.

   6 |
   7 | // Check that the entry is a valid entry
>  8 | checkFields<Diff<{
     |             ^
   9 |   GET?: Function
  10 |   HEAD?: Function
  11 |   OPTIONS?: Function
- info Linting and checking validity of types ...
```

I don't know where to start since I'm new to the NextJs front ,
tried to google the error but it isn't returning any relevant answers, bard AI is no help also

Comment: I'm also having a hard time with this but did you not face the error 'MISSING_NEXTAUTH_API_ROUTE_ERROR'
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300196/nextauth-error-missing-nextauth-api-route-error-in-next-js-13-app-route

Comment: Did you manage to get a fix for this in the end? I've tried the below comments but it still errors for me

Comment: Try remove export keyword and use "const authOptions".

Answer (score 28):

For me, the problem came from `export const authOptions` is in the `route.ts`

```js
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"

/* You shouldn't export authOptions in API route.ts / route.js file.
 This is the cause of error!! */

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
        }),
    ],
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

Just seperate `authOptions` file and then import the `authOptions` to your `[...nextauth]/route.ts`.

See also: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#supported-http-methods (you are only allowed to export HTTP Methods)

Comment: Your solution helped me! Thanks. After 2 hours of debugging....

Comment: It was hard to see cause there's a lot of examples with older versions and the error description wasn't clear for me. Thx for the help!

Comment: I've tried the above solution but it doesn't seem to work for me, is the code example you added imported from a particular folder location?

Comment: You need to split authOptions to another file. After that import it to [...nextauth]/route.ts

Comment: This change doesn't makes any sense, but worked. Thanks <3

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me!

Move the authOptions in a different folder

```
import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
        }),
    ],
}
```

And import into the `route.ts`

```
import { authOptions } from '@/lib/authOptions';

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

This is because you are only allowed to export HTTP Methods (`GET`, `HEAD`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc). If an unsupported method is called, Next.js will return an error. Link to the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#supported-http-methods).

Comment: This answer is an almost exact copy of the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76452264/8517948), if it helped you please consider upvoting it (once you have enough Reputation) but please don't repost an almost exact duplicate.

Comment: I prefer this answer. Thank you!

Comment: This answer is a copy, but there are an explanation. I also prefer this one.

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to export any arbitrary object when using a route.ts file in NextJS. You can only export objects named GET, POST, PATCH, etc. Since you are exporting authOptions, the build is failing.

If you need authOptions in another part of your app, you will need to move into a file other than route.ts. If you don't need authOptions in another part of your app, just get rid of the export and it should build.

Answer (score 1):

I was building an app with NextAuth recently and as I recall they still suggest you using 'pages' folder to handle all api requests. So you can try to:

1. create pages/api/auth folder in src directory
2. create file called [...nextauth].ts inside of it
3. create a file that would hold authOptions somewhere in your project, for example in features/lib
4. export your options from this file:

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {...}
```

and import them in your route to consume:

```
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Alternatively, you can configure your Next project to forget about TS errros when building as noted here: [link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-typescript-errors.md)

```
module.exports = {
  typescript: {
    // !! WARN !!
    // Dangerously allow production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has type errors.
    // !! WARN !!
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I tried ignoring the type errors in next config and it worked didn't try the pages method you mentioned because I had a doubt whether to nest the pages dir inside the app dir

Comment: You can use it alongside app dir in the same folder and it'll work

Comment: This looks more like a workaround rather than an actual fix because OP is already using the latest version of Nextjs and hence pages directory should be avoided.

Comment: @TusharShukla coming from official docs, this is the way: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example

Answer (score 1):

I am using Next js 14.0 and the error comes from  the api route.That is while exporting some function or variable from api route should be of  GET,POST,PUT,DELETE methods and other such CRUD operations only so that is the Type Error you are encountering.So the solution is to export authOptions from Other file eg: @lib/auth.ts

```
type TEntry = typeof import('../../../../../../app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js')

// Check that the entry is a valid entry
checkFields<Diff<{
  GET?: Function
  HEAD?: Function
  OPTIONS?: Function
  POST?: Function
  PUT?: Function
  DELETE?: Function
  PATCH?: Function
  config?: {}
  generateStaticParams?: Function
  revalidate?: RevalidateRange<TEntry> | false
  dynamic?: 'auto' | 'force-dynamic' | 'error' | 'force-static'
  dynamicParams?: boolean
  fetchCache?: 'auto' | 'force-no-store' | 'only-no-store' | 'default-no-store' | 'default-cache' | 'only-cache' | 'force-cache'
  preferredRegion?: 'auto' | 'global' | 'home' | string | string[]
  runtime?: 'nodejs' | 'experimental-edge' | 'edge'
  maxDuration?: number
  
}, TEntry, ''>>()
```

Here TEntry is taken from the function or variable you are exporting.So it should of this type otherwise it would return type Error

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had the following.  `export default async function POST(req: NextRequest) {}`
All I had to do was to remove the `default` keyword because next js expects multiple exports from the route.ts/js files.

So i ended up with `export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {}`

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is your imports try this :

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";    
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
        }),
    ],
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

so that mean change `AuthOption` to `NextAuthOptions` and `import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";`

Comment: Tried this method but didn't work still shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you encountered an error related to exporting a function in your **page.tsx** file. This error occurs when you export the **SkeletonCard** function. The error message indicates a type incompatibility issue.

Here's what I did to solve it:

```
   // page.tsx **before**

...

export function SkeletonCard() {
  return (
    <div className="py-20 container">
      {/* SkeletonCard implementation */}
    </div>
  );
}

const page = () => {
  return ...; // Your page implementation
};

export default page;
```

You noticed that removing the **export** statement for **SkeletonCard** resolved the error:

```
// page.tsx **after**

...

function SkeletonCard() {
  return (
    <div className="py-20 container">
      {/* SkeletonCard implementation */}
    </div>
  );
}

const page = () => {
  return ...; // Your page implementation
};

export default page;
```

After making this change, I were able to successfully build My Next.js project without encountering any errors.