# How to use prisma adapter next auth in Route Handlers

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

How to use next auth in Next js 13 with prisma adapter? it keep throw error.In [next auth prisma adapter dosc](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/prisma) only support `pages/api/` but I use the `app/api`.  I already tried a few code but this 2 only an example

*First Try*

`/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default NextAuth({
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
});
```

The problem is this is not supported in `app/` directory and throw error. It work fine actually if we remove the adapter but prisma will not read and create user to database.

**ERROR**

```
Error: PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser.
```

*Second try*

If we refer to the [next auth docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization) we can use app router, I also refer this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76298505/my-next-js-app-isnt-building-and-returing-a-type-error-how-do-i-fix) even with [this guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/other/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices) but still get an error.

`/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

```
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
        }),
    ],
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

**ERROR**

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invariant: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available
```

For reference my `db/prisma.ts`

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const globalForPrisma = globalThis as unknown as {
    prisma: PrismaClient | undefined
}

export const prisma = globalForPrisma.prisma ?? new PrismaClient()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalForPrisma.prisma = prisma
```

I really appreciated any help, if not clear refer to[my repo](https://github.com/dwissaaj/kisetsu.tech/tree/development) my repo

Answer (score 0):

I put what you have in `/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts` into `/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`, you can still use app directory for the rest of your project. If you move that file and follow the rest of the Prisma adapter docs you linked then everything should work.