# Nextjs isn't building with output: export because of missing "generateStaticParams()"

Tags: next.js, next-auth

My NextJS 13 app isn't building an app while output: export set.

It shows following error:

```
Error: Page "/api/auth/[...nextauth]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config.
    at D:\Projects\Thanksgiving\front\IHL-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:969:59
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Projects\Thanksgiving\front\IHL-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:105:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
    at async D:\Projects\Thanksgiving\front\IHL-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:862:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Projects\Thanksgiving\front\IHL-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:105:20)
    at async D:\Projects\Thanksgiving\front\IHL-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:801:124
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Projects\Thanksgiving\front\IHL-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:105:20)
    at async build (D:\Projects\Thanksgiving\front\IHL-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:185:29)
    at async main (D:\Projects\Thanksgiving\front\IHL-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next:157:5)
```

My project strucure:

```
- src
   middleware.js
- app
   favicon.ico
   globals.css
   layout.js
   loading.js
   page.js
  -- api
    --- auth
       baseaxios.js
      ---- [...nextauth]
         route.js
  -- assets
     loader.gif
  -- dislike
     layout.js
     page.js
    --- comments
      ---- [postid]
         Comment.module.css
         page.js
  -- forgot-password
     forgotPassword.module.css
     loading.js
     page.js
  -- like
     layout.js
     loading.js
     page.js
    --- comments
      ---- [postid]
         Comment.module.css
         page.js
  -- login
     loading.js
     login.module.css
     page.js
  -- password-change-confirm
     loading.js
     page.js
     PCC.module.css
  -- profile
     layout.js
     loading.js
     page.js
     Profile.module.css
  -- register
     loading.js
     page.js
     register.module.css
- components
   CheckWrapper.js
   Loader.js
   Posts.js
   Posts.module.css
   Provider.js
  -- AddPostButton
     PostButton.js
     PostButton.module.css
  -- Modals
     AddPost.js
     AddPost.module.css
  -- Query
     QueryProvider.js
  -- StatisticBar
     SBar.js
     SBar.module.css
- lib
   get-posts.js
   makeLike.js
   numberFormate.js
- pages
- redux
   ReduxProvider.js
   store.js
  -- features
     auth-slice.js
- schemas
   index.js
```

My route.js file:

```
const BACKEND_REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME = 90 * 24 * 60 * 60;
const SIGN_IN_HANDLERS = {
  "credentials": async (user, account, profile, email, credentials) => {
    return true;
  },
};
const SIGN_IN_PROVIDERS = Object.keys(SIGN_IN_HANDLERS);


export const authOptions = {

  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({

      name: 'Credentials',

      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "Password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const res = await axios.post("auth/login/", credentials, {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
          });

          const user = res.data; // Access the response data directly

          // If no error and we have user data, return it
          if (res.status === 200 && user && user.token && user.user) {
            return user;
          } else {
            throw new Error("Invalid response from authentication API");
          }

          // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
          return null;
        } catch (error) {
          // Handle error here
          return { error: "Invalid credentials" };
        }


      }
    }),

  ],

  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      if (!SIGN_IN_PROVIDERS.includes(account.provider)) return false;
      return SIGN_IN_HANDLERS[account.provider](
        user, account, profile, email, credentials
      );
    },
    async jwt({ user, token, account }) {
      // If `user` and `account` are set that means it is a login event
      if (user && account) {
        let backendResponse = account.provider === "credentials" ? user : account.meta;

        if (backendResponse && backendResponse.user && backendResponse.token) {
          token["user"] = backendResponse.user;
          token["token"] = backendResponse.token;
        } else {
          throw new Error("Invalid backend response for JWT token generation");
        }

        return token;
      }

      return token;
    },

    async session({ token }) {
      return token;
    },
  },

  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },

  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: BACKEND_REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME,
  },

}



const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

I've already tried to move authOptions to another folder as it was described here [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76298505/my-next-js-app-isnt-building-and-returing-a-type-error-how-do-i-fix) and downgrade next to 13.4.19 as it is suggested here : [text](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/56253), but the problem remains.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Page "/api/auth/[...nextauth]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config.

There is no `generateStaticParams()` function inside your `/api/auth/[...nextauth]` file

Read this
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params

And also this
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: Thanks, but this function is for authentication, and it's only post data to server , what static params could be generated with generateStaticParams()?

Comment: then why is the file named `[...nextauth]` if it isn't a dynamic route? You should change that to `nextauth` and it should work.

Comment: This naming from the next-auth docs : [Next-Auth](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app)