# in my next JS project i m recycling a modal component from another project but without using redux. I am getting a type error that crash my run build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-typescript

i m having this error :

```
.next/types/app/components/modal/page.ts:28:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<ModalProps, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'title' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  26 |
  27 | // Check the prop type of the entry function
> 28 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()
     |             ^
  29 |
```

when i am tryin to run a build version of my app and it crash. Otherwise the dev build run perfectly and i dont have any error.
it seem that it come from that component :

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './page.module.scss';

interface ModalProps {
    title: string;
    message: string;
    isOpen: boolean;
    onClose: () => void;
}

const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({ title, message, isOpen, onClose }) => {
    if (!isOpen) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.modalOverlay}>
        <div className={styles.modal}>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <p>{message}</p>
            <button className={styles.button} onClick={onClose}>Fermer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

and i m using it in that page for now :

```
import Modal from '../components/modal/page';

export default function Login() {
    const [isRegistered, setIsRegistered] = useState(true);   
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = useState('');
    const [modalMessage, setModalMessage] = useState('');
    const { isConnected, setIsConnected } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
```

...

```
if (response.status === 200) {
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data.token);
                sessionStorage.setItem('authToken', data.token)
                setModalTitle('Succès');
                setModalMessage(`Bonjour ${data.user.username}`);
                setIsModalOpen(true);
                setIsConnected(true);
            }
```

...

```
 <Modal
                    title={modalTitle}
                    message={modalMessage}
                    isOpen={isModalOpen}
                    onClose= {isConnected ? 
                        (
                            () => {setIsModalOpen(false);
                            router.push('/');}
                        ):(
                            () => {
                            setIsModalOpen(false);
                            router.push('/login');}
                        )
                    }
                />
```

i tryed multiple things but as junior dev i dont have a deep enough knowledge in next js gears. i also did some search over the net and the closer thing i could see is :

[My Next Js app isn't building and returing a type error, how do I fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76298505/my-next-js-app-isnt-building-and-returing-a-type-error-how-do-i-fix)

but i dont think the solution is accurate in my case.